# Calculating transform-origin's effect on element position

Tags: css, math, rotation, css-transforms

*Is there a way to calculate `transform-origin`'s effect on a rotated element's "position" (more like offset with respect to the document), regardless of the angle?*

Let's say we have a square, `100px * 100px` element that is rotated **90 degrees**, and it's `transform-origin` is `50px 50px`. As we can see from the picture below, the rotation origin is the center. *The white dot indicates the transformation origin.*

[image: The white dot indicates the transformation origin.]

But when we move the transformation origin, the element moves too. If we increase the transformation origin's x-axis by `1px` (`transform-origin: 51px 50px;`), the element seems to move **up** `1px` and **right** `1px`. Respectively, on the origin's y-axis a `1px` increase (`transform-origin: 50px 51px;`) moves the element **down** `1px` and **right** `1px`. So changes to even one of the transformation origin's axis values affect the element's position on both axes. If the origin's both values are increased in the same ratio, the effects kind of cancel each other out or reinforce each other.

Here is the same square with the `transform-origin` set as `75px 75px`, where the origin's y-value's "down"-effect has canceled the x-values "up"-effect, so the element has remained in the same position y-axis-wise. The "right"-effects of both values have added up, so the element has moved two times the effect's distance (`2 * 25px`) compared to only a single origin values' effect (`25px`).

[image: Transform-origin as 75px 75px]

So clearly it is possible to calculate the `transform-origin`'s effect on position, if you know the angle (in this case `90deg`). Can someone come up with a formula that enables the calculation with any angle or origin? (Ergo what would be the element's position compared to it's non-transformed state, if the `transform-origin` was for example `243px -35px` and the element would be rotated **270 degrees**.) I'm pretty sure it is possible to calculate, I just can't figure out how.

I'm not sure if I explained my problem understandably, so if you have any questions, ask!